# Duplicate table in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  employees e,
  departments d1,
  departments d2,
  departments d3,
  departments d4
WHERE e.dep1 = d1.dep(+)
AND e.dep2 = d2.dep(+)
AND e.dep3 = d3.dep(+)
AND e.dep4 = d4.dep(+);
```

Is there a better way to write this so that I don't need to use the same table in my query multiple times?  I know Oracle's optimizer probably works around this rather nicely, but if there is a more efficient way to write a query like this, I'm all ears.  Keep in mind that the above is merely an example, my actual query has a lot more going on in it.  I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.3 on Windows 2003 x64.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Based on the example, you'll still have to outer join four times and I agree that Oracle will handle it well. You can make your query a little easier to follow if you use ANSI join syntax - it will take all of the join logic out of the `WHERE` clause so you can concentrate on actual filtering logic there. The syntax would be `SELECT * FROM employees e LEFT JOIN departments d1 on e.dep1 = d1.dep LEFT JOIN departments d2 on e.dep2 = d2.dep...` and so on

Comment: This query will work fine. And it's the correct way to do it, if you really have a valid reason to model an `employee` with 4 `department` columns. What do they mean? I would give them better names than just 1..4

Comment: NB You only need an outer join if the dep1..dep4 columns can be null.

Comment: Right.  Without getting into the details of WHY I need to do this, I was just curious if there were any nice Oracle shortcuts that could cut down on the number of times I need to reference the table.  The outer joins were superfluous, and I probably should have omitted them (though I need them in my real query).  And I don't really understand the animosity towards the syntax I used above in favor of the ANSI JOIN syntax (which I personally find harder to read and understand at quick glance), but it seems to be a hot-button issue for a lot of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly valid.

The contrived example me and my colleague often use is `city_of_birth` and `city_of_residence`. Let's assume we want to query employees who now live in a different country to which they were born in (and that all countries have states).

You would query this as follows:

```
select e.*
from employees e,
     cities city_of_birth,
     cities city_of_residence,
     states state_of_birth,
     states state_of_residence
where e.city_of_birth_id = city_of_birth.id
  and e.city_of_residence_id = city_of_residence.id
  and city_of_birth.state_id = state_of_birth.id
  and city_of_residence.state_id = state_of_residence.id
  and state_of_birth.country_id != state_of_residence.country_id;
```

The thing to note is that tables need to be referenced in the `from` clause of a query as often as there are different meanings to them.

Another way to think about it: you need to reference the same table multiple times in the `from` clause if you're going to be selecting different rows from each "instance".

Comment: NB I've omitted the outer joins here for clarity because your query seems to emphasis the multiple references to a table in a query rather than the outer join part.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the details to all the departments flat in one row you need several joins but I suggest to write it this way:

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees e
 LEFT JOIN departments d1 on (   d1.dep = e.dep1 ) 
 LEFT JOIN departments d2 on (   d2.dep = e.dep1 ) 
 LEFT JOIN departments d3 on (   d3.dep = e.dep1 ) 
 LEFT JOIN departments d4 on (   d4.dep = e.dep1 )
```

Answer (score -1):

this doesn't make much sense to me... you are comparing an employee to find their department (when they have many possible in non-normalized columns) - what about using an OR clause...

```
SELECT *
FROM
  employees e,
  departments d
WHERE ( e.dep1 = d.dep
OR e.dep2 = d.dep
OR e.dep3 = d.dep
OR e.dep4 = d.dep );
```

or better - rework your table so it is properly structured. :)

Comment: This does something functionally completely different to the (correct) query posed in the question. Suppose dep1 is actually city_of_birth and dep2 is city_of_residence and you want to find all the employees who live in a different state to their place of birth. Then you'll need to join to `city` (which I'm substituting for department in my example) twice and thence each to `state`, also twice, and compare the found state_of_birth to the found state_of_residence. Got it?